# Update PHP for AiContactSafe to add multiple redirects dependent on Combobox Value

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, combobox

This may help a few people using Aicontactsafe with joomla as the core component does not have it currently as an option. Essentially i need to change the module php file to allow different redirect urls depending on what dropdown option is selected in the "Studio" Combobox field.

Perfectly honest with you i do not know if i am typing in the correct fields or code values:
The test site you can see here - http://www.datumcreative.com/wellness/ and the form is 'book my taster class' on the right.

Below is where i believe code needs adding in the original file:

```
if (!array_key_exists('return_to', $parameters)) {
// initialize the database
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
$query = 'SELECT redirect_on_success FROM #__aicontactsafe_profiles WHERE id = ' . $pf;
$db->setQuery( $query );
$redirect_on_success = $db->loadResult();
// set the return link to the current url or the one setup into the profile
if (strlen(trim($redirect_on_success)) == 0) {
    $postData['return_to'] = $currentUrl;
} else {
    $postData['return_to'] = $redirect_on_success;
}
  }
```

To create the other redirects i added the following custom lines, below the line "$redirect_on_success = $db->loadResult();":

```
 $redirect_to_wgc = "http://www.google.com";
```

$redirect_to_harp = "http://www.yahoo.co.uk";

I then needed to add the "if" statements **.

```
    **if ($field_values['aics_studio'] == "Welwyn Garden City") {
    $postData['return_to'] = $redirect_to_wgc; 
}
elseif ($field_values['$aics_studio'] == "Harpenden") {
    $postData['return_to'] = $redirect_to_harp; 
}**
elseif (strlen(trim($redirect_on_success)) == 0) {
    $postData['return_to'] = $currentUrl;
} else {
    $postData['return_to'] = $redirect_on_success;
}
```

No luck so far, any suggestions?

Comment: what do you get if you use `var_dump($field_values['aics_studio']);` ? Be sure to add this code outside of your `if else` statements. So add it underneath `loadResult();`

Comment: In the split second the form loads it normally says 'Please Wait...' now says NULL above it and then the functions do nothing like before. I added that line under - $redirect_on_success = $db->loadResult();
    var_dump($field_values['aics_studio']);